# визуальное превье сайта на табло

Tags: javascript, html, css, браузер

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как вы видите на этом табло, у каждого сайта имеется своя картинка для превье.. интересует.. из какого тега браузеры берут эту картинку?

`og:image` - не подходит

Comment: https://tech.yandex.ru/browser/tableau/?ncrnd=8552

Comment: @dzhioev, Оформите пожалуйста в виде ответа.

Comment: @LamerXaKer, мне лень

Answer (score 3):

Вместо `og:image` - `yandex-tableau-widget`

```
<meta name="yandex-tableau-widget" content="logo=logo.png, color=#ffffff, feed=feed.json" />
```

[Ссылку](https://tech.yandex.ru/browser/tableau/doc/dg/concepts/create-widget-docpage/#widget-in-head) на документацию уже [публиковали в комментариях выше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/472527/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8C%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE#comment531146_472527), плюсаните ему лишний раз)